# Pointer to a struct is not incrementing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, memory-address

I'm new to C language so there might be logical errors in this code which I don't know yet. There is a struct for card which has value and suit as fields.

My thought process for this code was:

- First, create a pointer to a card.
- Second, create card in a for loop and assign the fields of that card.
- Lastly, point to that created card and increment the pointer.

Repeat this process in order to create 52 cards in the memory addresses in a row.
Basically what I intended to do is creating a deck of cards for every 8 bytes in the memory, but the `card_ptr++;` line inside the loop doesn't work as I thought so. Any idea what is wrong here?

I tested the commented section and it increments the pointers by 8 bytes just as I wanted, but the loop doesn't do that. I also added print statements for helping you to understand what I'm thinking.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
  CLUBS,
  NUM_SUITS
} suit_t;

struct card_tag {
  unsigned value;
  suit_t suit;
};
typedef struct card_tag card_t;

int main(){ 

    card_t *card_ptr;
    printf("Initial card pointer created. %d\n", card_ptr);
    for(int i =SPADES; i < NUM_SUITS; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){
            card_t card;
            card.value = j;
            card.suit = i;
            printf("Card -> Value = %d Suit = %d, is created.\n", card.value, card.suit);
            card_ptr = &card;
            printf("%d points to the last card.\n", card_ptr);
            card_ptr++;
            printf("Pointer is incremented to %p\n\n", card_ptr);
        }   
    }

    /*card_t *card_ptr;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    card_ptr++;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    card_ptr++;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    */
}
```

Comment: Better make an array of type `cart_t` outside the loop and then access it with pointer.

Comment: I'm supposed to do it with pointers

Comment: use an array, assign the pointer to it & then access it using pointer. that's what I was saying.

Comment: @kiranBiradar *card_ptr is a pointer to a card_t and it is declared outside the loop.

Comment: @user10334659 So, you meant an array of card_t pointers to hold the memory addresses?

Comment: `printf("Initial card pointer created. %d\n", card_ptr);` invokes *undefined behavior* for two reasons. 1. `%d` is not the correct specifier for pointers, 2. `card_ptr` is not initialized, so it has an indeterminate value

Comment: @UnholySheep I don't have that error. This code compiles but the pointer doesn't increment inside the for loop.

Comment: @gunessun No, an array of type `card_t` accessed by a single pointer of `card_t` type - check this example (I have used `int` array for simplicity) https://ideone.com/Y4aC08

Comment: @gunessun your code invokes *undefined behavior*, that is not a compile-time error. It means your code can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @gunessun You don't want to use array and want to dynamically allocate?

Comment: Your code does not create 52 cards in memory. It creates one card at a time. It destroys that card when a loop iteration ends, and creates a new card when the next iteration starts. In order to create 52 cards, you need an array of 52 elements. Incrementing a pointer doesn't create a new card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code clearly lead to undefined behavior.
If you want to do it with pointers consider the below code.

1: First you need to declare the pointer to pointers.

`card_t **card_ptr = malloc(sizeof(card_t*)*NUM_SUITS);`

2: Then allocate the memory for each pointer.

`card_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(card_t)*14);`

3: Increment the pointer as below.

`card_ptr[i]++;`

4: free the memory using `free` after work done.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
  CLUBS,
  NUM_SUITS
} suit_t;

struct card_tag {
  unsigned value;
  suit_t suit;
};
typedef struct card_tag card_t;

int main(){ 

    card_t **card_ptr = malloc(sizeof(card_t*)*NUM_SUITS);
    if (card_ptr == NULL) return 0;

    printf("Initial card pointer created. %d\n", card_ptr);

    for(int i =SPADES; i < NUM_SUITS; i++){

        card_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(card_t)*14);
        if (card_ptr[i] == NULL) return 0;

        card_t *tempPtr = card_ptr[i];

        for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){

            tempPtr->value = j;
            tempPtr->suit = i;

            printf("Card -> Value = %d Suit = %d, is created.\n", tempPtr->value, tempPtr->suit);

            printf("%p points to the last card.\n", tempPtr);
            tempPtr++;
            printf("Pointer is incremented to %p\n\n", tempPtr);
        }   
    }

    /*card_t *card_ptr;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    card_ptr++;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    card_ptr++;
    printf("%d\n", card_ptr);
    */

     for(int i =SPADES; i < NUM_SUITS; i++){
        free(card_ptr[i]);
        card_ptr[i] = NULL;
     }
    free(card_ptr);
    card_ptr = NULL;

}
```

Comment: You'll be needing `stdlib.h` for that.

Comment: I guess the problem was I was allocating memory only for one card of space and that's why it wasn't incrementing, right?

Comment: This version uses a dynamically allocated array. One needs an array one way or another.

Comment: @gunessun Yes, also scope of the variable was very short.

Answer (score 1):

The larger issue here is the declaration scope of card. Local variables are allocated on the stack, and when they go out of scope, the memory is "freed" in a sense (available to be used elsewhere, although likely not re-initialized to zero). Your loop continually uses the same memory region, because card goes out of scope, and is re-created the next loop iteration.

As others have pointed out, you need to either statically declare an array of cards, or use malloc to ensure they stick around on the heap.

Using your code as a starting point, here's an example:

**Example (declare array of cards and iterate through using pointer)**:

```
card_t deck[52];

card_t *card_ptr = deck; /* Set pointer to the beginning of the array of cards */

printf("Initial card pointer created. %d\n", card_ptr);
for(int i =SPADES; i < NUM_SUITS; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){
        card_ptr->value = j;
        card_ptr->suit = i;
        printf("Card -> Value = %d Suit = %d, is created.\n", card_ptr->value, card_ptr->suit);
        printf("%d points to the last card.\n", card_ptr);
        card_ptr++;
        printf("Pointer is incremented to %p\n\n", card_ptr);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Artem sure, examples added

Comment: Dear Lasidar, thanks a lot for your comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes, I am aware, and indicated as much. It's purely to illustrate how the dynamic allocation could occur. He would need to maintain something like an array of pointers which reference the allocations for this to be proper.

Comment: Also undefined behavior when you do `card_ptr++;`

Comment: @kiranBiradar I removed the second example, because although it is illustrative of how the dynamic allocation could be done, it just leads to more confusion.